# Midnight commander and auto save panel folder

Tags: filesystems

I'm using Midnight Commander on Ubuntu Server 22.04. Any idea why it doesn't remember the last folder in panels?
It is really annoying to always moving through the tree of folders to the folder where I was before.

Comment: MC starts in the current directory, unless a different directory is given as an argument (for example, `mc /tmp`). This can be taken advantage of in a custom shell function or a script wrapper to call mc. You can also create quick access shortcuts (`C-\\`) for directories you use frequently.

Comment: Tnx. It would be very nice if MC could start where it was at last visit. But it looks this isn't possible (without additional tricks). Quick access shortcuts could be interesting sometimes, but I simply can't get used to it. Beside this, it has strange keyboard shortcuts on some keyboards (in my case, for example, the backslash comes after pressing AltGr and Q).